# How to get all notebooks/sections via GET notebooks/sections OneNote API

Tags: onenote

I tried GET notebooks API to get my all notebooks in Microsoft OneDrive.
When I owned 30 notebooks in OneDrive, the response JSON of GET notebooks API 
had only 20 notebooks information. Is this a bug or a feature?
(The GET notebooks API reference says, 'The GET verb with the notebooks resource path 
represents **all notebooks** to which a user has access in Microsoft OneDrive.')

In addition, the response JSON of GET notebooks API had "@odata.nextLink",
that value was "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks?$skip=20".
I thought that I could get rest of notebooks by the above url.
However, I got '501 Not Implemented' as the response of the above url.
The error response JSON was as follows.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "20111",
    "message": "OData Feature not implemented. Query option 'Skip.",
    "@api.url": "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=400828"
  }
}
```

Above issues applies to the GET sections API too.
What's the way to get all notebooks/sections via GET notebooks/sections API?

Comment: This is a recent bug that go introduced. We are going to work on fixing this immediately. It should in fact return ALL notebooks. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

Oops - this was our bad. We just fixed it. It should work for you now and return ALL of your Notebooks and Sections